# Dynamic javascript variables using struts property

Tags: javascript, struts2

How can I achieve something like mentioned below?

```
     var filterValues_<s:property value="moduleid"> = {
                "books" :
                    [
                     ["All","All"]
                     <s:if test="bookNames != null && bookNames.size != 0">
                     ,
                         <s:iterator value="bookNames" status="state" >
                             ["<s:property/>", "<s:property/>"]
                             <s:if test="!#state.last">,</s:if>
                         </s:iterator>
                     </s:if>    
                    ]
     }
```

I tried

```
var tmp = {};
var tmp["filterValues_<s:property value="moduleid">"] = {
            "books" :
                [
                 ["All","All"]
                 <s:if test="bookNames != null && bookNames.size != 0">
                 ,
                     <s:iterator value="bookNames" status="state" >
                         ["<s:property/>", "<s:property/>"]
                         <s:if test="!#state.last">,</s:if>
                     </s:iterator>
                 </s:if>    
               ]
    }
```

This works but is there any other way where i can have the name of the variable created dynamically using struts property tag?

I am displaying multiple gadget in my web page. UI code for each gadget goes into separate files. Each gadget can be added to the page multiple times and every gadgets gets a moduleid. using a normal variable name like "filterValues" causes the variable to be shared across gadgets, which i don't want. (how the script is loaded is a third party thing. I just fill in a template with code and rest is done by third party wars)

Comment: Eh ? Please explain what you are trying to achieve. That bunch of code is not clear at all

Comment: Your *solution* to dynamic variable name is ok. But your code looks very odd. Could you explain what are you trying to achieve with that? Sure there is a better way.

Comment: I have a jsp page where in the script tag I need to create a javascript variable with the name containing the value of "moduleid" (from value stack) for example if moduleid = 76 then variable name should be "filterValues_76"

Comment: Yes, we understand that part. But **why** do you need this? Give a bigger picture, so we could help you.

Comment: I am displaying multiple gadget in my web page. UI code for each gadget goes into separate files. Each gadget can be added to the page multiple times and every gadgets gets a moduleid. using a normal variable name like "filterValues" causes the variable to be shared across gadgets, which i don't want. (how the script is loaded is a third party thing. I just fill in a template with code and rest is done by third party wars)

Comment: It would be better if you could call an action with ajax and return json. But if that code works for you then it is ok.